# How do I solve this incompitable type error in java?

Tags: java, generics, types

There is a error when I try to give the value from last or first element in the linkedList to a new Item,`Item result = lastItem.previousNode.value;` it says incompitable type, required Item, found java.lang.Object. What did I do wrong and how do I fix this? Thank you.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

private int size;
private node<Item> firstItem  = new node<>();
private node<Item> lastItem = new node<>();

public Deque() {
    firstItem.previousNode = null;
    firstItem.nextNode = lastItem;
    lastItem.previousNode = firstItem;
    lastItem.nextNode = null;
    size = 0;
}                          // construct an empty deque

public boolean isEmpty() { return firstItem.nextNode == lastItem;}                // is the deque empty?

public int size() { return size;}                        // return the number of items on the deque

public void addFirst(Item item) {
    if(item == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("cant add null to deque");
    }

    if(firstItem.nextNode == lastItem){
        node nextItem = new node();
        nextItem.value = item;
        firstItem.nextNode = nextItem;
        nextItem.previousNode = firstItem;
        lastItem.previousNode = nextItem;
        nextItem.nextNode = lastItem;
    }
    else{
        node nextItem = new node();
        nextItem.value = item;
        firstItem.nextNode.previousNode = nextItem;
        nextItem.previousNode = firstItem;
        nextItem.nextNode = firstItem.nextNode;
        firstItem.nextNode = nextItem;
    }
    size++;
}         // add the item to the front

public void addLast(Item item) {
    if(item == null){
        throw new NullPointerException("cant add null to deque");
    }

    if(lastItem.previousNode == firstItem){
        node nextItem = new node();
        nextItem.value = item;
        firstItem.nextNode = nextItem;
        nextItem.previousNode = firstItem;
        lastItem.previousNode = nextItem;
        nextItem.nextNode = lastItem;
    }
    else {
        node nextItem = new node();
        nextItem.value = item;
        nextItem.previousNode = lastItem.previousNode;
        lastItem.previousNode = nextItem;
        nextItem.nextNode = lastItem;
        lastItem.previousNode.nextNode = nextItem;
    }
    size++;
}          // add the item to the end

public Item removeFirst(){
    if (firstItem.nextNode == lastItem) {
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Client tries to remove an Item from empty deque.");
    }
    node result = firstItem.nextNode;
    firstItem.nextNode = firstItem.nextNode.nextNode;
    firstItem.nextNode.nextNode.previousNode = firstItem;
    size--;
    return result.value;
}                // remove and return the item from the front

public Item removeLast() {
    if(lastItem.previousNode == firstItem){
        throw new NoSuchElementException("Client tries to remove an Item from empty deque.");
    }
    Item result = lastItem.previousNode.value;
    lastItem.previousNode = lastItem.previousNode.previousNode;
    lastItem.previousNode.nextNode = lastItem;
    size--;
    return result;
}                // remove and return the item from the end

public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    return new dequeIterator();
}        // return an iterator over items in order from front to end

    private class dequeIterator implements Iterator<Item>{
        private node<Item> nextNode = firstItem;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext(){
            return nextNode.nextNode != lastItem;
        }

        @Override
        public Item next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No next element available. Reached end of deque.");
            }

            Item returnValue = nextNode.value;
            nextNode = nextNode.nextNode;
            return returnValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove is not supported");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args){}   // unit testing (optional)

    private class node<Item>{
        private Item value;
        private node previousNode;
        private node nextNode;
    }
}
```

Comment: Either use the java collections classes; do not reinvent the wheel or don't ask StackOverflow to debug your classwork.

Comment: It's expecting an Item, but you're giving it an Object apparently. I'm not sure why you'd be using `Object`s. Rarely is there a need to use the Object superclass directly

Comment: You keep writing `new node()` everywhere, even though you have `node` as a generic class. You need to specify what type of `node` you want to create. Read up more on Java Generics.

Comment: @Fildor Outer classes can access everything inside of their inner classes

Comment: @petul. Ah, you are right. I miscounted "{}"s.

Comment: @Fildor You were right with the main method though, they miss their curly braces

Comment: @petul I assume c&p error. Fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your `node` class is redefining the generic that you intend to use. Do not do this. Simply use the generic `Item` inside `node` for declaring the value. You need not declare `node<Item>`. So, your `node` class become this:

```
private class node {
    private Item value;
    private node previousNode;
    private node nextNode;
}
```

Because of the re-declaration of the generic `Item`, it is unable to convert `node.Item` to `Deque.Item`. That is the reason for your error.

Also, you will need to remove any generics while instantiating `node` objects:

For example,

```
node<Item> firstItem  = new node<>();
```

will become:

```
node firstItem  = new node();
```

---

This will be your entire `Deque` class:

```
public class Deque<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {

    private int size;
    private node firstItem = new node();
    private node lastItem = new node();

    public Deque() {
        firstItem.previousNode = null;
        firstItem.nextNode = lastItem;
        lastItem.previousNode = firstItem;
        lastItem.nextNode = null;
        size = 0;
    } // construct an empty deque

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return firstItem.nextNode == lastItem;
    } // is the deque empty?

    public int size() {
        return size;
    } // return the number of items on the deque

    public void addFirst(Item item) {
        if (item == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("cant add null to deque");
        }

        if (firstItem.nextNode == lastItem) {
            node nextItem = new node();
            nextItem.value = item;
            firstItem.nextNode = nextItem;
            nextItem.previousNode = firstItem;
            lastItem.previousNode = nextItem;
            nextItem.nextNode = lastItem;
        } else {
            node nextItem = new node();
            nextItem.value = item;
            firstItem.nextNode.previousNode = nextItem;
            nextItem.previousNode = firstItem;
            nextItem.nextNode = firstItem.nextNode;
            firstItem.nextNode = nextItem;
        }
        size++;
    } // add the item to the front

    public void addLast(Item item) {
        if (item == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("cant add null to deque");
        }

        if (lastItem.previousNode == firstItem) {
            node nextItem = new node();
            nextItem.value = item;
            firstItem.nextNode = nextItem;
            nextItem.previousNode = firstItem;
            lastItem.previousNode = nextItem;
            nextItem.nextNode = lastItem;
        } else {
            node nextItem = new node();
            nextItem.value = item;
            nextItem.previousNode = lastItem.previousNode;
            lastItem.previousNode = nextItem;
            nextItem.nextNode = lastItem;
            lastItem.previousNode.nextNode = nextItem;
        }
        size++;
    } // add the item to the end

    public Item removeFirst() {
        if (firstItem.nextNode == lastItem) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Client tries to remove an Item from empty deque.");
        }
        node result = firstItem.nextNode;
        firstItem.nextNode = firstItem.nextNode.nextNode;
        firstItem.nextNode.nextNode.previousNode = firstItem;
        size--;
        return result.value;
    } // remove and return the item from the front

    public Item removeLast() {
        if (lastItem.previousNode == firstItem) {
            throw new NoSuchElementException("Client tries to remove an Item from empty deque.");
        }
        Item result = lastItem.previousNode.value;
        lastItem.previousNode = lastItem.previousNode.previousNode;
        lastItem.previousNode.nextNode = lastItem;
        size--;
        return result;
    } // remove and return the item from the end

    public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
        return new dequeIterator();
    } // return an iterator over items in order from front to end

    private class dequeIterator implements Iterator<Item> {
        private node nextNode = firstItem;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextNode.nextNode != lastItem;
        }

        @Override
        public Item next() {
            if (!hasNext()) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No next element available. Reached end of deque.");
            }

            Item returnValue = nextNode.value;
            nextNode = nextNode.nextNode;
            return returnValue;
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Remove is not supported");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    } // unit testing (optional)

    private class node {
        private Item value;
        private node previousNode;
        private node nextNode;
    }

}
```

PS: I would recommend usage of single letters such as E, K, I, etc for defining generics instead of a name like `Item`. It can easily be misunderstood to be a class.

---

Hope this helps!